# Can't start Selenium after reinstalling python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

Afeter reinstalling Python I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 5.19.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

My chrome was updated recently. Version 114.0.5735.133 (Official B Ubunuild) (64-bit). I just downloaded the lastest version of chromedriver from the official site [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/) and put it into the home folder after extracting.
My OS is Ubuntu 22
My initial program code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from datetime import datetime
import random
import schedule

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

the line that originates the error is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Path export in my shell config (.zshrc):

```
export PATH="/home/user/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver:$PATH"
```

Comment: Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you mentioned about downloading [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) from the official site [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/) containing ChromeDriver ***114.0*** but this error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 5.19.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

...implies that ***chromedriver=2.29.461571*** was effectively in use.

---

### Solution

Ensure that instead of *chromedriver=2.29.461571*, ***chromedriver=114.0*** is used.

Note: You may need to change the `Path` variable in your shell config (.zshrc):

```
export PATH="/home/user/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver:$PATH"
```